# JQuery Autocomplete JSON empty results

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

Currently autocomplete is firing, returning empty rows under the textbox.

Empty Rows shown under textbox.

How to get return json values into search textbox?

I need to add more details to get this form to submit.

View

```
<input type="text" class="sicautocomplete" placeholder="search by SIC Code" />
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult SICCodeSearch(string term)
{
    var siccodes = LogicEngineLifetime.Database.SICCodes
        .Where(s => s.Code.ToString()
        .Contains(term))
        .Distinct()
        .Select(x => x.Code)
        .Take(100)
        .ToList();
    return Json(siccodes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JS:

```
$(".sicautocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
        jQuery.get(sicCodesURL, { term: request.term }, function (data) {
            // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
            // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
            // and not a string
            response(data);
        });
    },     
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item)
            $(this).val('');
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var a = ui.item;
        $(".sicautocomplete").val("");
        return false;
    }
});

//$(".sicautocomplete").autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, c) {
//    return $("<li></li>")
//  .data("item.autocomplete", c)
//  .append(c)
//  .appendTo(ul);
//};
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. It should be `response($.map(data, function (item) { return { label: item, value: item }}));` but the code in your `focus`, `change` and `select` events dont really make sense. Also using `.Distinct()` before the `.Select()` does not make sense

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you solved my problem.  How do I award you answer points?

Comment: I didn't add an answer because I'm still confused by your other code (in the `change` and `select`) and what your trying to achieve with those